# SQL Server 2008 - Fill Same Value Based On The Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query and having a difficult time to figure out how to fill the same value based on one column. Let me explain what I am trying to accomplish....

Says, I have a table like this below with too columns: Name & Value. So, "*Select Name, Value FROM Table1 Order By Name*" will produce the following result.

```
Table1

Name    Value   
AAA     111
AAA     
BBB     222
BBB     
BBB     
BBB     
CCC     333
CCC     
DDD     444 
DDD     
DDD
```

Now, What I am trying to accomplish is producing the result below with the "Select .... from Table1" query.

Table1

```
Name    Value   
AAA     111
AAA     111
BBB     222
BBB     222
BBB     222
BBB     222
CCC     333
CCC     333
DDD     444 
DDD     444
DDD     444
```

Please help and provide the sample code if possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `MAX()` as a window function:

```
SELECT Name, Value,
       MAX(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) as imputed_name
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Name;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I need to learn more about "Over Partition" and how it was able to fill in that value and produce that result.